# Wireless on Acer Aspire One & Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, acer, ubuntu-netbook

I'm really new to Ubuntu, used it only a little 5 or so years ago and remember having wifi obstacles then too. I bought a crappy Acer Aspire One Netbook recently that came with Ubuntu on it, ethernet works fine and I tried installing some wireless stuff from the Software Center and uninstalled it after a friend told me the wireless driver for the netbook I have is different. Did some searching... I don't know what to do... I feel so dumb and helpless.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the output of `lspci | grep -i Network` on a terminal.

Comment: Please open a terminal ctrl+alt+t copy and paste the following commands into it one line at a time, then edit your question to contain the results of these commands.  

`cat /etc/lsb-release; uname -a`
`lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`
`lsusb`
`iwconfig`
`rfkill list all`
`lsmod`